# Sort an array in specific order javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this

```
arr1 = ["P2.13","P1.13","P4.13","P3.13", "P2.14","P2.14","P1.14","P4.14","P1.15","P2.15","P3.15","P4.15"];
```

How can I sort the array by the number after the dot FIRST, from 13 to 15, then sort by the number after "P" from 1 to 4? Finaly I want an array like this

```
arr2 = ["P1.13","P2.13","P3.13","P4.13","P1.14","P2.14","P3.14","P4.14","P1.15","P2.15","P3.15","P4.15"];
```

Appreciate!!

Comment: Show what have you tried first

Comment: Check out the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method. You can pass it a custom comparison function to determine how it's sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For programs that include many functional programming I choose Underscore library.
You can directly call sortBy function based on multiple attributes with a hacky trick by joining them. Here is the code:

```
var sortedArray = _.sortBy(arr1, function(item) {
    var nums = item.split('.');
    return [nums[1], nums[0]].join("_");
});
```

However, you can still use Javascript sort function to sort list with customized compare function. Here is the code:

```
arr1.sort(function(x, y) {
  var numsX = x.split('.');
  var numsY = y.split('.');
  if (numsX[1] !== numsY[1]) { 
    return compare(numsX[1], numsY[1]);  // compare the number after dot first
  }
  return compare(numsX[0], numsY[0]); // compare the number before dot after
});

// General comparison function for convenience
function compare(x, y) {
  if (x === y) {
    return 0;
  }
  return x > y ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Check two examples on fiddle
[Underscore sort](https://jsfiddle.net/johnnyzh82/zqmsawk8/) vs
[Javscript sort](https://jsfiddle.net/johnnyzh82/oLn5wzft/)

This is my new account, I don't have reputation to post more than 2 links. You can search underscore library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a function into `sort`. The following will work for the precise test case provided, but would need to be modified if the input is more general.

```
arr1.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.slice(-2) - b.slice(-2) || a[1] - b[1];
});
```

Note that this will *mutate* `arr1`.